# How to center an image in the middle of the window in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, centering

So I am Loading an Image in python and I need to Center the Image in Pygame. As Pygame starts the drawing from the upper left side of the screen so the x and y coordinates 0,0 doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the center x and y coordinates of the pygame window?

Comment: It's half of both width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the center of the window through the window rectangle ([`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect)):

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```

```py
center = screen.get_rect().center
```

Use this to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) an `image` ([`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) object) in the center of the screen:

```py
screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center))
```

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0). However, the position of the rectangle can be specified with a keyword argument. In this case, the center of the rectangle is set by the center of the screen.
When the 2nd argument of [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is a rectangle ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)), the upper left corner of the rectangle will be used as the position for the `blit`.

Comment: Oh ok. I misunderstood the code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know how to load a jpg image file in pygame? When I load them it doesn't show in the screen but a png image does.

Comment: @DebarkaNaskar jpg can be loaded the same way as png with [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load). Make sure the image path and file extension is correct. If you're using Windows, make sure the name of the image isn't something like "name.jpg.jgp". Note that the file extension is hidden in Explorer by default.

Comment: Thanks again! I noticed that I made a typo and when I fixed it all worked fine.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you! I used to think we had to manually subtract `centerx` and `centery`, now I know that we don't!