# How to center an image in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to display a custom png file in a pygame screen, but when I call...

```py
screen.blit(image, screen.get_rect().center)
```

...it centers the image's upper left corner on the coordinates.

How can I fix this so that the center of the image is on the coordinates? Already referenced the following answer, but it didn't change my image position: [How to centre an image in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420908/how-to-centre-an-image-in-pygame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How to center an image in the middle of the window in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530062/how-to-center-an-image-in-the-middle-of-the-window-in-pygame/70530198#70530198). If you want to center the image in the middle of the screen, you need to get the bounding rectangle of the image and set the center of the rectangle to the center of the screen:

<s>`screen.blit(image, screen.get_rect().center)`</s>

```py
screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center))
```

The same in single steps:

```py
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
screen_center = screen_rect.center
image_rect = image.get_rect()
image_rect.center = screen_center 
screen.blit(image, image_rect)
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image = pygame.image.load("image.png")

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```